# Barcode scanning on Android?

Tags: android, barcode, google-vision

I have an app for android which has a feature for scanning barcodes and I'm currently using *Google Vision* library in the project, it was functional til a couple of days ago, which gives the following error:

```
06-04 12:19:18.979  6752  9626 I ChmraDebugLogger: [11] com.google.android.gms.vision.barcode
06-04 12:19:18.987 15536 16738 W DynamiteModule: Local module descriptor class for com.google.android.gms.vision.barcode not found.
06-04 12:19:18.987 15536 16738 I DynamiteModule: Considering local module com.google.android.gms.vision.barcode:0 and remote module com.google.android.gms.vision.barcode:0
06-04 12:19:18.988 15536 16738 E Vision  : Error loading module com.google.android.gms.vision.barcode optional module true: gf: No acceptable module found. Local version is 0 and remote version is 0.
06-04 12:19:18.988 15536 16738 I Vision  : Request download for engine barcode is a no-op because rate limiting
06-04 12:19:18.989 15536 16738 W DynamiteModule: Local module descriptor class for com.google.android.gms.vision.dynamite.barcode not found.
06-04 12:19:18.990  6752  9626 W ProviderHelper: Unknown dynamite feature vision.dynamite.barcode
06-04 12:19:18.998 15536 16738 I DynamiteModule: Considering local module com.google.android.gms.vision.dynamite.barcode:0 and remote module com.google.android.gms.vision.dynamite.barcode:0
```

and I dug a lot and tried many solutions including clearing data, revoking and granting camera permission and so ... But none of them worked.

I ask if there's any solution that I might have forgotten to test or there is a better open source library (**excluding ZXing** because it's in maintenance mode) which I can use.

**NOTE: The most important part of the log is `Request download for engine barcode is a no-op because rate limiting` and I have no idea why it's happening.**

Comment: you can also use firebase vision one, there is already an example repo on github

Comment: @Abdul - Firbase MLKit is in beta phase and I cannot use it in production.

Comment: Have you tried Google's [sample code](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-vision/tree/master/visionSamples/barcode-reader)?

Answer (score 1):

I was using Zxing library like many developers for a long time, but I have started using journeyapps, after Zxing enter Maintenance Mode. You can definitely check it, I am using this library in a serious business app with no problem since more than 1 year. Approximately 300.000 barcode scanning every day with phone camera. This is the link: https://github.com/journeyapps/zxing-android-embedded

Comment: I thank for you suggestion but personally preferred [https://github.com/dm77/barcodescanner](https://github.com/dm77/barcodescanner)

Answer (score 0):

You can try Google's sample code (https://github.com/googlesamples/android-vision/tree/master/visionSamples/barcode-reader) to verify whether GMS can normally work.

If your GMS cannot work, you may need to update it. If your GMS can work, refer to Google's sample code to modify your project.

Comment: If you've read the question properly, I've mentioned that I'm using vision, and based on google sample codes

Comment: So?  You didn't mention whether Google's sample code can work or not.

Comment: Yes, it was working until I hit the problem: `Request download for engine barcode is a no-op because rate limiting` and I don't have a clue of why!

Comment: @MaskedMan I recently tested Google's code, and everything worked well on my system. What's your GMS version?

Comment: It was `18.0.0` but I updated to `20.1.0` and the problem persists.

Comment: @MaskedMan my version is 20.18.17. Have you tried other mobile vision samples? Probably all of them cannot work due to your current gms version.

Comment: No that's not the case, the major problem is it's download is rate limited.